# How to declare a one-method trait

Tags: scala, traits

In scala, there are multiple ways to declare a trait with only one method

```
trait OneMethod extends (A => B)

trait OneMethod {
  def myMethod(a: A) : B
}
```

What are the pro and con of each solution ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By extending `(A => B)`, you are saying that `OneMethod` *is* a function, and can be used directly as such:

```
trait TraitA extends (Int => String)
class ClassA extends TraitA { def apply(i: Int) = i.toString }

val a = new ClassA
(1 to 5).map(a)      // IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

If you don't extend `(A => B)`, you can't do that; instead, you'd have to tell it explicitly what the method name is:

```
trait TraitB { def myMethod(i: Int): String }
class ClassB extends TraitB { def myMethod(i: Int) = i.toString }

val b = new ClassB
(1 to 5).map(b)              // error, required: Int => ?
(1 to 5).map(b.myMethod)     // IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

So: extending `(A => B)` makes your class a bit more flexible in its use, with less verbosity.  On the other hand, if you want a more descriptive name than `apply`, you can do version B.

Also worth noting: neither version restricts the trait to having only one method; you can add extra methods to either.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the pro of both solutions using the following approach:

```
trait Transformer[A, B] extends (A => B) {
  override def apply(a: A): B = transform(a)
  def transform(a: A): B
}

object FooTransformer extends Transformer[String, String] {
  override def transform(a: String): String = a + ", world"
}

val transformer = FooTransformer

// "classic" usage
val foo = "hello"
// "hello, world"
val transformedFoo = transformer.transform(foo) 

// functional usage
val fooList = List("foo", "bar", "baz")
// List("foo, world", "bar, world", "baz, world")
val transformedFooList = fooList map transformer
```

This gives you flexibility and descriptiveness because you can use it both as a function and in a *classic* fashion.